# UISearchBar in control segments

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift4

I have a search bar that can be used to search for any item in the control segments ( all the shops ). And the control segment to filter the shop.

So :

the search is for all shops

the segments is to filter the shops

Here is how I saved the selected index

```
s.valueChange = { index in
            switch index {
            case 0 :
                self.selectedIndex = 0
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            case 1 :
                self.selectedIndex = 1
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            case 2 :
                self.selectedIndex = 2
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            case 3 :
                self.selectedIndex = 3
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            default:
                self.selectedIndex = 0
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
```

And this is number of rows in section

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searchActive {
            return auxiliar.count
        } else {

        switch selectedIndex {
        case 0:
            return  allShops.count
        case 1:
            return self.coffee.count
        case 2:
            return self.restuarnt.count
        case 3:
            return self.pharmacy.count

        default:
            return   allShops.count
        }

        }
    }
```

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

```
    if searchActive

    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ShopTableViewCell
        let entry1 = auxiliar[indexPath.row]
        cell.shopName.text = entry1.shopname

        return cell
    } else {
    switch selectedIndex {
    case 0:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ShopTableViewCell
        let entry = shops[indexPath.row]
        cell.shopName.text = entry.shopname

        return cell

    case 1 :
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ShopTableViewCell
        let entry = coffee[indexPath.row]
        cell.shopName.text = entry.shopname
        return cell

    case 2 :
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ShopTableViewCell
        let entry = restuarnt[indexPath.row]
        cell.shopName.text = entry.shopname
        return cell

    case 3 :
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ShopTableViewCell
        let entry = pharmacy[indexPath.row]
        cell.shopName.text = entry.shopname
        return cell

    default:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ShopTableViewCell
        let entry = shops[indexPath.row]
        cell.shopName.text = entry.shopname
        return cell
    }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        if searchActive {


            guard (auxiliar.count) > indexPath.row else {
                print("Index out of range")
                return
            }
            let meal1 = auxiliar[indexPath.row]
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerIdentifer") as! MealsDetailsController
            viewController.passedValue = (meal1.familiy_id)
            viewController.name = (meal1.shopname)
            print("\(meal1.familiy_id) im the search ")
            view.animateRandom()
            self.present(viewController, animated: true , completion: nil)

        } else {
        switch selectedIndex {
        case 0  :
            let meal1 =  shops[indexPath.row]
            guard (shops.count) > indexPath.row else {
                print("Index out of range")
                return
            }
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerIdentifer") as! MealsDetailsController
            viewController.passedValue = (meal1.familiy_id)
            viewController.name = (meal1.shopname)
            print("\(meal1.familiy_id) im the search ")
            view.animateRandom()
            self.present(viewController, animated: true , completion: nil)

        case 1 :
            let meal1 =  coffee[indexPath.row]

            guard (coffee.count) > indexPath.row else {
                print("Index out of range")
                return
            }

... the rest of the cases
```

And finally the  textDidChange

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        auxiliar = shops.filter { $0.shopname.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil}
        if searchText == "" || searchBar.text == nil {
            auxiliar = shops
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }


  func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
    {
        self.searchActive = true
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
    {
        self.searchActive = true
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
    {
        self.searchActive = false
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
    {
        self.searchActive = false
    }

    func searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchActive = false

    }
```

**The Problem**

When I search for a shop the results are coming fine in all the segments. But **when I end the search and change the segments all the segments after search has the rows of segment 0 ( selectedIndex = 0 )** and never change again

Also when I click on the X button inside search bar the app crashes

What I want :

After ending search and search bar is "" or nill, I want to click on any segment and the shops belong to that segment appear.

Comment: I think the problem is that make searchActive = true in searchBarTextDidEndEditing method it should be false

Comment: I did change it to false but now when I search in a different segment and click on the cell the app crashes

Comment: I think the crash happen because you select in wrong array ]

Comment: How Can I avoid searchActive when the user taps on the outside of the keyboard I can detect the user tap and change searchActive to false ?